# Google App Engine ApiProxy delegate NullPointerException on saving file

Tags: java, google-app-engine, spring-boot, nullpointerexception, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to save a file to Google App Engine and following their documentation, but constantly getting the NullPointerException on the CreateOrReplace method line. Already figured it out that gcsService is created. Any ideas?

```
public String getFileUrl(MultipartFile file) throws CustomException {

    String unique = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    String fileName = unique + ".jpeg";

    GcsFilename gcsFilename = new GcsFilename("MY_BUCKET", fileName);

    try {
        GcsOutputChannel outputChannel = GcsServiceFactory.createGcsService().createOrReplace(gcsFilename, GcsFileOptions.getDefaultInstance());
        copy(file.getInputStream(), Channels.newOutputStream(outputChannel));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    ImagesService imagesService = ImagesServiceFactory.getImagesService();

    ServingUrlOptions options = ServingUrlOptions.Builder
            .withGoogleStorageFileName("/gs/MY_BUCKET/" + fileName)
            .secureUrl(true);

    return imagesService.getServingUrl(options);
}
```

Included dependency:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine.tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-gcs-client</artifactId>
        <version>0.7</version>
    </dependency>
```

And getting the:

```
RetryHelper(32.34 s, 6 attempts, com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.GcsServiceImpl$1@74c3f0b0): Too many failures, giving up
```

With the exception in the log:

```
c.g.a.tools.cloudstorage.RetryHelper     : RetryHelper(1.386 s, x attempts, com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.GcsServiceImpl$1@6bd1dbe9): Attempt #x failed [java.io.IOException: java.lang.NullPointerException], sleeping for x ms
```

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:**

Found that ApiProxy class in com.google.apphosting.api on

```
public static ApiProxy.Delegate getDelegate() {
    return delegate;
}
```

returns NULL.

Any ideas?

Comment: Without a [mcve] it would be impossible to help you. In the current state the only way we can help is to give you hint/instruction to debug your program, which is not on-topic for [so].

Comment: Thanks, @user202729. Hopefully, It is more clear now.

Comment: If this is Java, you should have the [tag:java] tag.

Comment: Yup, added that as well. Thanks!

Comment: Where do you have this method defined: `copy(file.getInputStream(), Channels.newOutputStream(outputChannel));` ?

Comment: In the same class, just copied it from the documentation, but it breaks on CreateOrReplace method. Any ideas? @VictorHerasmePerez

Comment: What I actually want is the code for the method. Can you post the link to the doc so I can have the complete example?

Comment: Yeah, no problem @VictorHerasmePerez https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-gcs-client/blob/master/java/example/src/main/java/com/google/appengine/demos/GcsExampleServlet.java